# Spring boot admin without embedded Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, tcserver, spring-boot-admin

I'm trying to deploy spring-boot `.war` application on standalone servlet container (Pivotal tc Server) and have issue with spring-boot admin page.
When I run app using `spring-boot:run` command, I have proper boot spring-boot admin UI page,
but when I deploy war on tcServer, on root path `/` I see spring-boot admin page without any applications inside it:
How I enable admin page:

```
  @EnableAdminServer
    public class AppRunner extends SpringBootServletInitializer { ... }
```

In properties I set:

`server.port=9000`

When running tcServer I see in logs:

> jvm 1    | [2017.08.18 12:42:04.180 AST] [WARN ]
>   [d.c.b.a.s.ApplicationRegistrator] [pool-3-thread-1] [Failed to 
>   register application as null  at spring-boot-admin
>   http://localhost:9000/api/applications): serviceUrl must be set when 
>   deployed to servlet-container]

tcServer is ran on 8080 default port.
Can anybody give advice how to see my app in spring-boot admin UI on external server?

Comment: any reason to downvote?

Comment: I edited my question to remove all unclear moments..but i think if anyone want to help it's more productive to ask in comment rather than downvote..

Comment: Which version do you use ? Could this apply: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/260 ? Have you set serviceUrl ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved this by adding property:

```
spring.boot.admin.client.service-url=http://localhost:9000
```

To the `application.properties` config.

Comment: Man I spent far too long trying to figure out what that value was supposed to be. Thank you.